# How to make to display the button which I need in my template Django?

Tags: django-templates

I need:

1) If a user has created a object of the class by a form, then he sees the button which calls the webpage of the object detail.

2)  If a user didn't create a object of the class, but another user did it, then he sees the button which calls this form to create a object and the user will be a author this object.

3) If a user didn't create a object of the class by a form, then he sees the button which calls this form.

If a user didn't create a object of the class, but another user did it, then he sees the button which calls this form to create a object and the user will be a author this object.

I made this:

```
{% if list %}
    {% for i in list %}
        {% if request.user == i.author %}
            <a class="btn" href="{% url 'detail' i.id %}" role="button">
              {{i.detail}}
            </a>
        {% else %}
           <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form">
                 the form button
           </button>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% else %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#digital">
      Кнопка для вызова формы
    </button>
{% endif %}
```

But if a user created a object of the class, then he sees both button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py

```
class MyClassCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CustomSuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
model = MyClass
template_name = 'mypage.html'
form_class = MyClassForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('mypage')
success_msg = 'сохранён'
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['list_mylist'] = MyClass.objects.all()
    list_mylist = kwargs['list_mylist']
    for i in list_mylist:
        if i.author == self.request.user:
            print('my_button')
            kwargs['my_button'] = True
            break
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

template

```
        {% if my_button %}
       {% for i in list_mylist %}
             {% if request.user == i.author %}
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
                  кнопка первая
                </a>
             {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#class">
          кнопка вторая
        </button><br>
    {% endif %}
```